# Laravel sum total value of other column

Tags: laravel, database, controller

I want this output

| id | jml | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 1 | 100 | 1100 |
| 2 | 400 | 400 |
| 2 | 300 | 700 |

but when i try my output is

| id | jml | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 400 | 400 |
| 2 | 300 | 300 |

I try this to take sum of column

```
$total = DB::table('logs')
         ->groupBy('id')
         ->sum('jml');
```

and this to add new input

```
$total += $request->jml;
$total = (string)$total;
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is here. Is the table in the question your current result or what you expect to have? What do you currently have?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the expected output

Comment: that table is the thing I want as output in the database

Comment: Logically it doesnt make sense to group by id and sum, as id most likely is unique

Comment: so how can I get the sum of the same id values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using an laravel eloquent model

```
$total = Log::sum('jml');
```

or it might work using the laravel DB class like this

```
$total = DB::table('logs')->sum('jml');
```

Comment: if i want to sum with the same id, how do i do?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer should do all ID numbers even duplicate ID numbers.

However you can also use this version which might be easier to understand and verify.

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
$results = Log::get();

if(!empty($results)) {
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $sum = $sum + $result->jml;
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work for all ID's even duplicate ID numbers.
However you can also do it this way.

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
$results = Log::get();

if(!empty($results)) {
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $sum = $sum + $result->jml;
    }
}

echo $sum;
```